# Object != nil works in Beta 5 but not in Beta 6?

Tags: swift

I left an project unattended for months, only last week installed Beta 5, it worked after fixing a ton of 'nil' errors in **AppDelegate.swift** and today tried Beta 6, 'nil' errors again?

```
func saveContext () {
    var error: NSError? = nil
    let managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext
    if managedObjectContext  != nil {
        if managedObjectContext.hasChanges && !managedObjectContext.save(&error) {

            abort()
        }
    }
}

var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext {
    if _managedObjectContext == nil {
        let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
        if coordinator != nil {
            _managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext()
            _managedObjectContext!.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
        }
    }
    return _managedObjectContext!
}
```

The errors says, specifically at this line

```
if managedObjectContext  != nil {

'Cannot invoke '!=' with an argument list of type (NSManagedObjectContext, NilLiteralConvertable)'
```

and

```
if coordinator != nil {

'Cannot invoke '!=' with an argument list of type (NSPersistantStoreCoordinator, NilLiteralConvertable)'
```

It worked in Beta 5, so did I miss anything in the patch notes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is due to a few changes in Xcode 6 beta 6 (see the [release notes](http://adcdownload.apple.com//Developer_Tools/xcode_6_beta_6_gl2i5q/xcode_6__beta_6_release_notes.pdf)).

In particular:

> Non-optional types may no longer be compared to nil, and ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional no longer conforms to BooleanType.

Your `managedObjectContext` variable is of non-optional type `NSManagedObjectContext`. It cannot be nil and so the check was useless and is now forbidden.

I don't know about the return type of your `self.persistentStoreCoordinator`, but most likely it's also a non-optional.

The solution is simple: remove the `if` checks. They aren't needed.

BTW, also of interest is this change, which is slightly related:

> A large number of Foundation APIs have been audited for optional conformance, removing a
>   significant number of implicitly unwrapped optionals from their interfaces. This clarifies the
>   nullability of their properties and arguments / return values of their methods. This is an ongoing
>   effort since beta 5.

Comment: BTW after upgrade to Beta6 I found some extra validations in my code that you can remove

Comment: The secret hint in the error message is that it says `NSManagedObjectContext` instead of `NSManagedObjectContext?`.